# How to add the customer header to the Excel Sheet -closed xml package

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, closedxml

I need to add customer headers to the Excel sheet, which are programmatically created in c# using a closed XML package. I want to go generate the Excel sheet like this below.

```
+---------------------------------------+-----------
|Generated till : current month         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------
|reported generate time: current time
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
|           | current     | renewal     |  Total    |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Month     | Emp.Count   |   Emp.Count | Emp.Count |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| Dec 22    | 10          |    12       | 22        |
| Nov 22    | 8           |     2       | 10        |
| Oct 22    | 3           |     3       |6          |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|Total      | 21          |  17         |38         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

But, I am unable to get like that. My coding like below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[8] 
{ 
    new DataColumn("Billing Description"),
    new DataColumn("Month"),
    new DataColumn("Emp.Count New"),
    new DataColumn("Emp.Count Renewal"),
    new DataColumn("Emp.Count Total")
});

List<student> details = new StudentRepository().GetCount();

for(int i=0; i< details.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add((i+1) + "Month  Billing",
        details[i].Month,
        details[i].new, 
        details[i].renewl,
        
        details[i].total,
    );
}

using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wb.SaveAs(stream);
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Summary.xlsx");
    }
}
```

I have tried to add the row, but it's over-writing on the columns header. Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the headers to a new worksheet and then insert the datatable to an specific cell. for example:

```
      using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
      {
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add();
        ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Generated till : current month";
        ws.Cell(2, 1).Value = "reported generate time: current time";
        ws.Cell(3, 1).InsertTable(dt);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
          wb.SaveAs(stream);
          return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Summary.xlsx");
        }
      }
```

Comment: I am getting a null exception for getting the instance of the worksheet. I want to create the 4 worksheets. so, I am trying as below.
            worksheet.IXLWorksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet.Name = "Summary";
            worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = header1;

Comment: @KalaiSelvi ,try `wb.Worksheets.Add(string sheetName)` method instead  and it returns the Worksheet objects. for example `IXLWorksheet worksheet1 =  wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");` and so on